# Is there a way to start a project multiple times in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I would like to simultaneously start multiple instances of a project using Visual Studio. By pressing F5 (Debug -> Start Debugging), at most 1 instance of each project in the solution starts, respectively. I didn't find a way to configure startup of multiple instances of the same project.

The project in question is a console app that is difficult to convert in a way to enable multiple instances within the project.

Comment: If I remember right, you should be able to start multiple instances of VS and start the project within each of them.

Comment: @Nodebody: Yes, that's possible but quite cumbersome - I was hoping for an easier way

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you are looking for simultaneously, I don't know.
But you can try right Click on the Project Debug -> Start new instance as many times as you like.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to debug you can start multiples instances ("Start Without Debugging")
[image]

In case you want to debug an instance you could then [attach the debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6wf8e4z.aspx) to it.
If attaching the debugger is not an option you could use System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break() method in your code. The equivalent but programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to debug multiple instances of a project using a single project. The IDE/debugger need to synchronize program execution with source code and debugging symbols; it can't do that unless there's only one instance.

You could, however, copy your project multiple times and start them as you describe (as a solution).

Answer (score 0):

Select and Right click any project. Then debug and Start New Instance

[image: Running a project multiple times in Visual Studio]